# usage of boost::addable2 - why the returned result from operator+ is reversed

Tags: c++, boost

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "boost/operators.hpp"

using namespace std;

class simple_string : private boost::addable1<simple_string,
                              boost::addable2<simple_string, const char*> > 
{
public:
  simple_string() : m_str("Default")
  {}

  explicit simple_string(const char* s) : m_str(s)
  {}

  simple_string(const simple_string& rhs) : m_str(rhs.m_str)
  {}

  simple_string operator+=(const simple_string& rhs)
  {
    m_str += rhs.m_str;
    return *this;
  }

  simple_string operator+=(const char* rhs)
  {
    this->operator+=(simple_string(rhs));
    return *this;
  }

  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const simple_string& si)
  {
    os << si.m_str;
    return os;
  }

private:
  string m_str;
};

int main(void)
{
  simple_string s1;
  simple_string s2(s1);
  cout << "[before] s2: " << s2 << endl;

  s2 += s1;
  cout << "s2 += s1: " << s2 << endl;

  simple_string s3 = s1 + s2;
  cout << "s3: " << s3 << endl;

  simple_string s4 = s3 + "Why";
  simple_string s5 = "Now" + s3;
  cout << "s4: " << s4 << endl;
  cout << "s5: " << s5 << endl;
  cout << "Now" + simple_string() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
~/Documents/C++/boost $ g++ -o p123 p123.cpp
~/Documents/C++/boost $ ./p123
[before] s2: Default
s2 += s1: DefaultDefault
s3: DefaultDefaultDefault
s4: DefaultDefaultDefaultWhy
s5: DefaultDefaultDefaultNow
DefaultNow
~/Documents/C++/boost $
```

**Question**> Why the generated `operator+(const char*, const simple_string&)` doesn't not return the correct result?

For example, the expected result for `s5` should be `s5: NowDefaultDefaultDefault`

and the result for `"Now" + simple_string()` should be `NowDefault`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that for strings `operator+` is not commutative, but the boost implementation assumes that it is. See the symmetry note at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/libs/utility/operators.htm#symmetry for details.

EDIT: Upon reading the actual boost code I think I was wrong. You just can't use the boost operator generation for classes for which `operator+` isn't commutative as that's an implicit assumption within boost. You'll have to implement it yourself.

Original answer based on (I believe) incorrectly reading the docs:

You can force possibly less efficient code that doesn't assume symmetry as shown here:

`...if your code relies on the function signature or a strict symmetric behaviour, you should set BOOST_FORCE_SYMMETRIC_OPERATORS in your user-config. This will force the NRVO-friendly implementation to be used even for compilers that don't implement the NRVO.`

Comment: It is my opinion after reading the docs and agreeing with your answer that it would be easier and more clear to simply implement the operators you want for these non-commutative cases, although that doesn't really answer the question.